# can not find specific events and list events of the past the last 1day

Tags: web3js, etherscan, ens

I'm wrote this sample but I want to filter specific events 'unsealBid' and list  events of
the past (e.g. the last 1 or 2 days).

```js
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/65386ae7c95b446c889a41405aec48e1');

const abi = [{ "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_hash", "type": "bytes32" }], "name": "releaseDeed", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "_hash", "type": "bytes32" }], "name": "getAllowedTime", "outputs": [{ "name": "timestamp", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "unhashedName", "type": "string" }], "name": "invalidateName", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "hash", "type": "bytes32" }, { "name": "owner", "type": "address" }, { "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "salt", "type": "bytes32" }], "name": "shaBid", "outputs": [{ "name": "sealedBid", "type": "bytes32" }], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "bidder", "type": "address" }, { "name": "seal", "type": "bytes32" }], "name": "cancelBid", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "_hash", "type": "bytes32" }], "name": "entries", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint8" }, { "name": "", "type": "address" }, { "name": "", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "ens", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_hash", "type": "bytes32" }, { "name": "_value", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_salt", "type": "bytes32" }], "name": "unsealBid", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_hash", "type": "bytes32" }], "name": "transferRegistrars", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }, { "name": "", "type": "bytes32" }], "name": "sealedBids", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "_hash", "type": "bytes32" }], "name": "state", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint8" }], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_hash", "type": "bytes32" }, { "name": "newOwner", "type": "address" }], "name": "transfer", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "_hash", "type": "bytes32" }, { "name": "_timestamp", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "isAllowed", "outputs": [{ "name": "allowed", "type": "bool" }], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_hash", "type": "bytes32" }], "name": "finalizeAuction", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "registryStarted", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "launchLength", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint32" }], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "sealedBid", "type": "bytes32" }], "name": "newBid", "outputs": [], "payable": true, "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "labels", "type": "bytes32[]" }], "name": "eraseNode", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_hashes", "type": "bytes32[]" }], "name": "startAuctions", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "hash", "type": "bytes32" }, { "name": "deed", "type": "address" }, { "name": "registrationDate", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "acceptRegistrarTransfer", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_hash", "type": "bytes32" }], "name": "startAuction", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "rootNode", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "bytes32" }], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "hashes", "type": "bytes32[]" }, { "name": "sealedBid", "type": "bytes32" }], "name": "startAuctionsAndBid", "outputs": [], "payable": true, "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "name": "_ens", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_rootNode", "type": "bytes32" }, { "name": "_startDate", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "type": "constructor" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "hash", "type": "bytes32" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "registrationDate", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "AuctionStarted", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "hash", "type": "bytes32" }, { "indexed": true, "name": "bidder", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "deposit", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "NewBid", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "hash", "type": "bytes32" }, { "indexed": true, "name": "owner", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "status", "type": "uint8" }], "name": "BidRevealed", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "hash", "type": "bytes32" }, { "indexed": true, "name": "owner", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "registrationDate", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "HashRegistered", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "hash", "type": "bytes32" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "HashReleased", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "hash", "type": "bytes32" }, { "indexed": true, "name": "name", "type": "string" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "registrationDate", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "HashInvalidated", "type": "event" }];
const address = '0x6090A6e47849629b7245Dfa1Ca21D94cd15878Ef';

const contact = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);


contact.getPastEvents('AllEvents', 
    {
        //filter: {myIndexedParam: [1,44], myOtherIndexedParam: '0x47872b42'}, // Using an array means OR: e.g. 20 or 23
        fromBlock: 6614389   ,
        //fromBlock: web3.eth.getBlockNumber('latest') - (60 * 60 * 24 * 7) / 14,
        toBlock: 'latest'
    }, (err, events) => {
        console.log(events);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
contact.BidRevealed({fromBlock: 6614389, toBlock: 'latest' }).get(function(err, logs){console.log(logs)}
```

Comment: What is the account  {'from': account}?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake I fix it. btw there is no event called unsealBid in that contract, there is a function called unsealBid

Comment: `
contact."unsealBid"({fromBlock: 6614389, toBlock: 'latest' }).
get(function(err, logs){console.log(logs)});`   ?

Comment: ahmed, unsealBid is not an event, is a function, thats why you do not see events for unsealBid

Comment: this is my task :r list or visualize the ENS contract events of
the past (e.g. the last 1 or 2 days). focussing in particular on the bid revelation event:
unsealBid(bytes32 _hash, uint256 _value, bytes32 _salt)

Comment: Again, unsealBid is not an event, is a function. What you have as event is `BidRevealed(bytes32 indexed hash, address indexed owner, uint value, uint8 status);` See the update on my answer. Although this will work in your original solution. Your problem is that you are looking for unsealBid but that is not an event, instead look for `BidRevealed` and check the status arguments of the log.